# Adding displayed SVG to canvas keeps existing size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, svg

So this is a strange one.

I have a bunch of SVG thumbnails rendered on the screen.  When you click one, it draws it onto the canvas.  It doesn't read that image, it just takes the URL and re-requests it to re draw.

Except the canvas renders it the same size as the thumbnail.  Even though it fetches a URL.  If I add `new Date().getTime()` to the URL param it works.  But it re-downloads it. which seems overkill to me.

My potential solution is to preload the SVGs at full height in a hidden div and render those into the thumbnails.  This feels pretty hacky though.

Has anybody else run into something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're going to need to give us a [mcve]

Comment: A few solutions, one is to insert the SVG as inline HTML. If the full size SVG is tiny, I'd just load all of it. Or if you are doing it within SVG, try inserting it as a `<image ...  xlink:href="path/to/image.svg"></image>`

Comment: The download twice thing may happen when you do use `<object>` or `<iframe>`, since the request headers are different than the one from an `<img>` tag. The size problem is really odd and you'll have to show us how you do things so we can help you.